# Forward slashes having variable number of path parameter in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have made an API in Flask which has the following route defined.

`@app.route("/<project>/<branch>/<patch>")`

Everything works as expected, however, the issue is, at times, there is a possibility that the `branch` parameter contains two words seperated by a forward slash, like this: `a/b`.

My function on top of which I have the route defined works fine when the request is something like this:

`https://webservice-hostname/abc/def/ghi`

But, it fails to work in cases when the request is on the URL like this: 
`https://webservice-hostname/abc/def/ghi/jkl`

In this case, I want it to be like this:

```
project = abc
branch = def/ghi
patch = jkl
```

Also, in my case it is guaranteed that only the branch variable can sometimes have two words (seperated by a forward slash) or have a single word. The other variables are guaranteed to be single word.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Is'nt this a case of using URLEncoding ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the flask `path` routing converter https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#routing to pass the entire route including slashes through to your view function as a single variable.

```
@app.route("/<path:project_branch_patch>")
```

For your simple use case where only branch can contain a slash it may be easier to just define two routes with a default value for the case where there is no contained slash.

```
@app.route("/<project>/<branch1>/<patch>", defaults={"branch2": ""})
@app.route("/<project>/<branch1>/<branch2>/<patch>")
def myview(project, branch1, branch2, patch):
    branch = "{}/{}".format(branch1, branch2) if branch2 else branch1
```